# list comprehension question

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is there a way to add multiple items to a list in a list comprehension per iteration? For example:

```
y = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
x = [1,2,3]

return [x, a for a in y]
```

output: `[[1,2,3], 'a', [1,2,3], 'b', [1,2,3], 'c', [1,2,3], 'd']`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sure there is, but not with a plain list comprehension:

EDIT: Inspired by another answer:

```
y = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
x = [1,2,3]

return sum([[x, a] for a in y],[])
```

How it works:  sum will add a sequence of anythings, so long as there is a `__add__` member to do the work.  BUT, it starts of with an initial total of 0.  You can't add 0 to a list, but you can give `sum()` another starting value.  Here we use an empty list.

If, instead of needing an actual list, you wanted just a generator, you can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, which just strings a bunch of iterators into one long iterator.

```
from itertools import *

return chain.from_iterable((x,a) for a in y)
```

or an even more itertools friendly:

```
return itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.izip(itertools.repeat(x),y))
```

There are other ways, too, of course:  To start with, we can improve Adam Rosenfield's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289659/list-comprehension-question/4289695#4289695) by eliminating an unneeded lambda expression:

```
return reduce(list.__add__,([x, a] for a in y))
```

since list already has a member that does exactly what we need.  We could achieve the same using `map` and side effects in `list.extend`:

```
l = []
map(l.extend,[[x, a] for a in y])
return l
```

Finally, lets go for a pure list comprehension that is as inelegant as possible:

```
return [ y[i/2] if i%2 else x for i in range(len(y)*2)]
```

Comment: Hmm, I liked your earlier version, it looked cleaner. This looks less readable

Comment: . . . 'chain.from_iterable' is available in Python 2.6+

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
y = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
x = [1,2,3]

return reduce(lambda a,b:a+b, [[x,a] for a in y])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
z = []

[z.extend([x, a]) for a in y]
```

(The correct value will be in z)